# how to Invoke jsf validation message on InputText change event

Tags: validation, jsf, myeclipse

I have been trying to this but no success , What I want is when User enters some text i.e. numeric,  it should be checked onchange event and if its wrong a message should be displayed on h:message tag

My Managed Bean Name: first

**Below Code is working but for h:commandButton

// XHTML

```
     <h:message for="sub" style="color:RED"></h:message>

//managedBean
    private UIComponent input;


    public UIComponent getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(UIComponent input) {
        this.input = input;
    }
```

public void checkFirstLengthValue(){

```
if(someValue!=null && !someValue.equals("")){
    int UserEnteredValue=Integer.parseInt(someValue);
    if(UserEnteredValue>dataLength.getEndingLength() || UserEnteredValue<dataLength.getStartingLength()){
        someValue="";


         FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Invalid length");
         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         context.addMessage(input.getClientId(context), message);

    }
    }
}
```

But I want something like this

```
   //XHTML
    <h:inputText id="firstlength" binding="#{first.input}" validator="#{first.checkFirstLengthValue()}" onchange="#{first.checkFirstLengthValue()}" value="#{first.someValue}"> 
<f:ajax> event="change" listener="#{first.checkFirstLengthValue()}" </f:ajax>   
          </h:inputText> 
  <h:message for="firstlength" style="color:RED"></h:message>
```

the checkFirstLengthValue() method is same as written above.
so Can this be done, I am trying but it isn't working. If there's some other method do let me know I want to call the managed-Bean and that method will invoke the h:message for the inputText

Comment: its not a duplicate question check again

Comment: It's indeed not a duplicate question. It's the answer which is a duplicate. So, when being referred to a duplicate, you should ignore the question and look at the answer.